# jQuery How to display a selected image in dynamically loaded tabs (currently only works on first tab)

Tags: jquery, image

I am dynamically creating tabs and on each tab I display an image. I then allow a new image to be selected to replace it. When the new image is selected on the first tab it is displayed (the original image displayed is replaced). However, on the subsequent tabs the original image is not replaced (the new image name is displayed). There is no error in the console.

So in my research I found the solution "$(document).on". Which I was able to get working for my dates and buttons (similar issues). However, I can not get this to work for my image selection. This is my code and what I have tried:

```
//I have changed this:
//      $("#photo").change(function(){
//      readURL(this);
//      });

    $(document).on('change', '#photo', function(){
        readURL(this);
    });

    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#campImage').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    //I have tried this and it does not display the image even on the first tab:
    //      function readURL(input) {
    //          if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    //              var reader = new FileReader();
    //              
    //              $(document).on('onload', 'reader', function(e) {
    //                  $('#campImage').attr('src', e.target.result);
    //              })
    //              
    //              reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    //          }
    //      }
```

HTML:

```
//Column 2 to contain the image
contents += '<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">';
contents += '<label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" for="photo">Photograph:</label>';
contents += '<input class="form-control-file col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8" type="file" id="photo" name="photo" placeholder="Photograph">';
contents += '<img id="campImage" src="' + obj.eventPicture + '" alt="Camp image" class="img-thumbnail">';
contents += '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is to make each "id=" unique. In this case id="photo" needs to change to "id="'+obj.eventId+'"' and "id="campImage""chages to "id="campImage'+obj.eventId+'"".The eventId is the primary key for the row in the table and is therefore unique.

The code is:

```
        //Column 2 to contain the image
        contents += '<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">';
        contents += '<label class="control-label control-label-left col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" for="'+obj.eventId+'">Photograph:</label>';
        contents += '<input class="form-control-file col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 photo-input" type="file" id="'+obj.eventId+'" name="photo" placeholder="Photograph">';
        contents += '<img id="campImage'+obj.eventId+'" src="' + obj.eventPicture + '" alt="Camp image" class="img-thumbnail">';
        contents += '</div>';
```

So you now ask, if the "id" changes each time how do I recognise it has changed? Well in the class add a unique name, I use "photo-input" and use that. So the JS is:

```
    $(document).on('change', '.photo-input', function(){
        alert("this.id: " + this.id);
        readURL(this, this.id);
    });

    function readURL(input, id) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#campImage'+id).attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
```

So, you will notice that I have id set to a unique value for each tab. I then append that value to the input id that I want to populate (picture is not the only one in this form, I have kept this simple).